# How would I make a batch that asks user input for timeout time?

Tags: batch, hibernate, user, input

I have a batch that allows me to hibernate with timeout but now I would like it to ask me the time for timeout.

So it would be something like below:

1. Batch asks for `%value%`: (user would write a number that would then be the `%value%`)
2. Then batch would write `timeout /t %attrb% /nobreak shutdown /h`

Or it could also wait for given value and then run command `/shutdown /h`

Is it possible and if it is, then how?

If this is not possible with a batch file, should I try Visual Basic or what?

Comment: nvm i think i solved it already:

@echo off
set /P TOValue= timeout time:

timeout /t %TOValue% /nobreak & shutdown /h

pause


feel free to use it though.. its useful

Comment: Did you use `set /p`?

Comment: @Samu You can create your own answer and accept it.  That way the question doesn't stay 'open' and others can directly see the solution.

Comment: I see in [self-answer](http://superuser.com/help/self-answer) you need to wait 8 hours (if <100 reputation) to self-answer (and 48 hours before accepting a self-answer) but please don't let that stop you from doing it.

Comment: doing it atm.. think i will have to wait to accept it

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself and actually made a pretty decent batch.

I've uploaded the batch code to pastebin for 1month if u want to check it out.

If u want to see the batch after that time please let me know and contact me thru email s1200439(at)student.businesscollege.fi

Here is the batch code: http://pastebin.com/ai5skfkQ

Also forgot to add that if u write DEMO in the choosetool it will make the batch to go into demo version where u can try the batch without actually shutting down ur machine.